# Subtract one day on all time stamps touched today in whole system- windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, powershell, timestamp

In my windows-7 PC due to cmos battery failure I have to set date time.But i did wrongly i.e set 14th August instead of 13th August. And I found very late after a lot of work done.

Now I want to change the all timestamps(created date, modified date, ..) of all files in the whole system that touched today(created date of all files which created today,modified date of
all files modified today) to correct date

It would be better atleast to change timestamp of  my working files(folders, archived files, .Net related files such as c# source code files, aspx files, sln files ,etc..,)

Any script or command utility available in PowerShell or any thing on Windows 7 to subtract one day from timestamps of files touched today

**Secondary question:**
          Is it possible to change all history, bookmarks items' timestamp of a browser like Google chrome simillarly?

Comment: Just use the `datemodified:` using the built-in search within Windows.

Answer (score 1):

found out after lot of googling

```
$SubtractDays = New-Object System TimeSpan 1,0,0,0,0
(Get-ChildItem D:\ -Recurse | Where {($_.LastWriteTime).date -eq (Get-Date).date})| ForEach-Object {$_.LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime.Subtract($SubtratDays)}
(Get-ChildItem D:\ -Recurse | Where {($_.CreationTime).date -eq (Get-Date).date})| ForEach-Object {$_.CreationTime = $_.CreationTime.Subtract($SubtratDays)}
```